# How work the ordering of parameters in an owl-s perform?

Tags: semantics, owl

Owl-s [ontology](http://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/) describe an programing language for web services (like [bpel]).
What is the way to use the process binding in a perform to tell the ordering of the parameters in an Owl-s Process ?

**example:**
Considere this call :

myProcess(myFirstParameter, mySecondParameter)

In owl-s we get something like this :

```
Perform(MyProcess,hasDataFrom(Binding(TheParam(myFirParameter), TheParam(MySecondParameter) )))
```

What are the axiom(s) to add to the ontology to tell the process that the correct call is
is:

```
  myProcess(myFirstParameter, mySecondParameter)
```

and not:

```
  myProcess(mySecondParameter, myFirstParameter)
```

?

The section [5.5 Specifying Data Flow and Parameter Bindings](http://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/#sec_dataflow) of the w3c submission give very little information about this. And I can't find an example of an non atomic process using more than one parameters or not relying on the WSDL binding. Can someone show me an example of parameters binding that work ?

**Context of the question :**

- WSDL is not an option because the services to perfome can be : human,
  rest, kqml ... (and also wsdl but not all).
- Right now, my ontology is encoded as java class(one class
  per-concept), so I am using an ArrayList for the parameter ordering.
  But tomorow I have to export it.

Comment: Have you had a look at the example in that document with `<process:AtomicProcess rdf:ID="Purchase">`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The Purchase example is an atomicProcess. So the description of the process is how to call it, not how to perform it. The problem only involve compositeProcess. This is closely related to the section 5.5 : How to bind a variable to the parameter number x ? Parameters get an ID but this ID is not use to bind; the resource ID is show only once in the document.